# Customizing the Azure B2C Signup Page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to customize my Azure B2C Policy sign up sign in policy. I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool). I created my custom sign up sign in page and I have the sign in page the way I want it to look, but when I click "Sign up now" a form for the user information shows with default styling. How do I style this page? I wish to reuse the html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by [Customize your policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool#customize-your-policy), you must:

1. Select **Sign-up or sign-in policies**, select your built-in policy, and then select **Edit**.
2. Select **Page UI customization**.
3. Select **Local account sign-up page**, set **Use custom template** to **Yes**, and then enter the absolute URL to your HTML file in the **Custom page URI** field.